# Sort inline citations by overall order of appearance

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I've seen many posts about getting the citation list in order of appearance, but my issue differs slightly and I wasn't able to find it in other posts...

I'm wondering if there's a way to sort citations inline by their order of appearance in the text. Here's an example:

```
Main body of text with first citation \cite{source_1}. Second citation here \cite{source_2}. 
For fun here's another \cite{source_3}.
Further on I don't want to worry about correctly ordering my references and would like to 
cite them like this \cite{source_2, source_3, source_1}.
```

The result looks like this:

> Main body of text with first citation [1]. Second citation here [2]. For fun here's another [3]. Further on I don't want to worry about correctly ordering my references and would like to cite them like this [2, 3, 1].

What I'd like to see is the group citation display the references as "[1, 2, 3]" (or ideally "[1-3]") rather than the order I listed them in the editor. `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` has gotten me 90% of the way to how I want this formatted but the last few details are eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [cite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package, it does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{a,
    author = {A},
    year = {2001},
    title = {A},
  }
  @book{b,
    author = {B},
    year = {2002},
    title = {B},
  }
  @book{c,
    author = {C},
    year = {2003},
    title = {C},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\cite{a}
\cite{b}
\cite{c}
\cite{b,a,c}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

It gives the expected output:

> [1] [2] [3] [1-3]

It also provides options for disabling sorting or compressing (e.g. that you get [1,2,3] with options `[nocompress]`)